# Refresh data in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

In my main form I have a refresh button.

[image]

the problem is when I tried clicking it, it won't refresh nothing happened.

Below is my code for the refresh button.

```
Private Sub ToolStripButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                                  Handles ToolStripButton2.Click
       ResidentsDataGridView.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: Using a DataSource like a DataTable, you "refresh" that source, not the control.  If you have a form level dataadapter and a datatable as a datasource the only time you need to "refresh" is if you need to pick up new rows from other users, server/db supplied data from triggers, AI IDs, timestamps etc. Otherwise all the data is always there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Refresh() is inherited from Control and has nothing to do with the data in your DataGridView.

To refresh it you need to "refresh" the source of the DataGridView.
So if you are filling the DataGridView from a DataTable. Repopulate that DataTable.

Comment: You've confused the WinForms [`DataGridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) which does not have a `DataBind` method with the `GridView` in the `Web.UI.WebControls` Namespace which does.

Comment: Opps, very true. Edited.